# HowTo Meteor + jQuery + BigVideo.js

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm brand new to meteor and a JS neophyte. However, I am proceeding boldly. Perhaps a little too boldly since I'm trying to use a third-party library not yet packaged for Meteor.

For simplicities sake, I'm modifying the sample simple-todo app. Though I've removed the ifClient and ifServer conditionals and divvied up the code and put it in appropriate ./client, ./server, and ./both directories. The app works after my mods. Now, I'm trying to get the BigVideo module to render a video background.

I've added jquery with

```
wmodes$ cd myproject
wmodes$ meteor add jquery
jquery: Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
```

I've unzipped the BigVideo.js library into myproject/client/lib:

```
wmodes$ ls client/lib/BigVideo.js-master/
BigVideo.jquery.json bower.json           lib
README.md            css
wmodes$ ls client/lib/BigVideo.js-master/lib/
bigvideo.js
```

And I've added the suggested BigVideo code at the bottom of  myproject/client/simple-todos.js

```
$(function() {
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
    BV.init();
    if (Modernizr.touch) {
      BV.show('public/images/oceans.mp4');
    } else {
      BV.show([
        { type: "video/mp4",  src: "public/video/oceans.mp4" }
        // { type: "video/webm", src: "vids/river.webm" },
        // { type: "video/ogg",  src: "vids/river.ogv" }
      ]);
    }
});
```

I start Meteor with no errors, but no video background either.

What am I missing?

Comment: add the suggested BigVideo code inside a `TemplateName.rendered` callback. see if that works.

Comment: Can you show us the Template where you are displaying the video ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, mostly by fiddling.

First, I untarred the BigVideo.js source into client/lib.

```
$ ls client/lib/bigvideo/
BigVideo.jquery.json bower.json           lib
README.md            css
```

The template is really nothing special, just a placeholders within which BigVideo inserts its own divs.

```
<div id="section2" class="section section3x">
    <div id="trigger2"></div>
    <div id="content2" class="content full">
        <h2>Scene 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus placerat egestas sem, eu ultricies dolor imperdiet eu. Nulla scelerisque vitae nisl at tempus. Sed mollis libero sit amet metus scelerisque consectetur. Sed eget maximus nisl. Curabitur rhoncus porttitor porttitor. Morbi nec fringilla felis. Maecenas condimentum a lectus nec vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I set all the defaults and options and called BigVideo.

```
// Fullscreen background video
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
$(function() {
    isTouch = Modernizr.touch;
    var bigvideoDefaults = {
        useFlashForFirefox:false,
        forceAutoplay:false,
        controls:false,
        doLoop:true,
        shrinkable:false,
    }
    var bigvideoSettings = $.extend({}, bigvideoDefaults, {
        container:$('#content2')
    });
    BV = new $.BigVideo(bigvideoSettings);

    BV.init();
    BV.show([
        { type: "video/mp4",  
            src: "/video/p00-sunny-window-loop.mp4"},
        { type: "video/webm", 
            src: "/video/p00-sunny-window-loop.webm"},
        { type: "video/ogg",  
            src: "/video/p00-sunny-window-loop.ogv"}
    ]);
    BV.getPlayer().pause();
});
```

This is probably not the most efficient method, but it works. I could probably scrunch that down into a few lines, but it is verbose for the sake of my understanding. Suggestions are welcome.

I am particularly dubious of the way I defined a BigVideo object, and then modify it later. I wanted to have access to the var because a little further on, I use scrollmagic to trigger the video on and off:

```
// Trigger background video start and end
var scene = new ScrollScene({
    offset: -winUnit/2,
    triggerElement: "#content2",
    duration: winUnit*(fullDelay*2),
    //pushFollowers: false,
})
    .on("start end", function (e) {
        BV.getPlayer().play()
    })
    .on("enter leave", function (e) {
        BV.getPlayer().pause()
    })
    .addTo(controller)
    .addIndicators({suffix: '2b'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to have BigVideo as a source for your background video, and any video will do, then this solution may work well for you:

```css
/* Put this in your CSS file */

/* This code comes from http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video */

video#bgvideo { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -100;
  background: url(stillImage.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}

video { 
  display: block; 
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
  html {
    background: url(stillImage.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
  #bgvideo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Insert this code between your <body></body> tags -->

<!-- Also from http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video -->

<video autoplay poster="stillImage.jpg" loop id="bgvideo">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```